# How to remove the negative component of a sine wave?

Tags: signal, diode-clamp

The following is the schematics of a simple circuit I'm working on, It filters and amplifies an electret condenser microphone's signal to get an output ranging from 0 to 9V (to drive an equalizer like leds not a speaker):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fil8bA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The mic signal passes first through a low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of around 20Khz, then gets coupled with a 47nF capacitor, then gets offset by 1/2 VCC by a voltage divider, then amplified 1000 times using 3 noninverting amplifiers with a gain of 10 each.

Now the next stage I want to clamp the negative part of the signal, to do that I put a reverse biased diode after a coupling capacitor. But after testing the signal appears to pass through unchanged. Why is it not getting clamped?

### Update:

If I disconnect the non-inverting input of the last opamp from the diode and measure the voltage at the junction between C6 and D1 I get a nice clampped singal between -0.6V and 3V (I had to increase C6 to 100uF though).

Comment: You want to clamp your circuit or clip your circuit?  Shift signal up or simply remove values below 0?

Comment: how big is the signal? What is the forward conduction voltage of that diode?

Comment: R11 and C7 form a low pass filter, not a high pass.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the signal is -1mv to 1mv and the diode is 1N4148 with a 0.6 forward drop voltage.

Comment: Does your circuit have an error? Are both inputs of your 4th opamp really tied together? Assuming they're not, you probably have some DC biasing issues on the non-inverting input. Tie it to ground with a large-value resistor (check your opamp's datasheet for its input bias current spec).

Comment: So ... ? Does your circuit (as you've drawn it in your question) have an error (as I asked above)? And ltspice is certainly smart enough to simulate an opamp's input bias currents (if the opamp model includes them).

Comment: No no errors whatsoever, everything seems to be working except for the C6 coupling capacitor and the diode, I replaced R8 with 1Mohm but nothing changed except for the last amplifier output.

Comment: Here's the ltspice file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9AbIe6liw3BMTctYTJsaFFCcjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, 1mV is a lot less than 0.6V so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @BrianDrummond 1mv is the source signal, the C6 coupling capacitor sees 3 to 6v signal.

Comment: So what voltages do you see at the diode?

Comment: So you're saying that you've deliberately shorted the 4th opamp's inputs together? How is that supposed to work? Your observation that disconnecting the opamp from C6 & D1 only goes towards confirming the opamp input bias current issue.

Comment: @pjc50 It depends on C6 value, with 100nF the diode sees the same signal as C6 but shifted down by 1V, with 100uF the diode sees the same signal.

Comment: @brhans I'm not sure what do you mean, if you are refering to the update I just posted I simply disconnected the 4th opamp noninverting input to test the voltage at the C6, D1 junction. It's not a fix.

Comment: Just look at the schematic you've posted in your question. Look at the inputs to the the 4th opamp. They are connected together. Is that correct? Do not look at your ltspice. I'm not asking you about your ltspice. Look at what you have posed in *this question* on *this site*.

Comment: @brhans thanks for pointing that out it's a wiring mistake, I fixed the schematics above, however the ltspice simulation I'm testing on my pc doesn't have this error, you can see the ltspice file I linked in the comments above.

Comment: So now you need to deal with the opamp's **Input Bias Current**. You need a DC path for this current otherwise it will just charge up your coupling cap C6. Put a resistor in parallel with D1 - probably a 1M will work.

Comment: Aside from that, you might also want to google for *precision rectifier* circuits to see what the common ways to do this are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) OpAmp you're using has an Input Bias Current spec (from table 6.5 on pg.5 of the DS) of typically 45nA.
If you refer to the internal schematic diagram in Fig.16 on pg.13:
[image]
you can see where this current comes from.
The current from the 6uA source is split between the 2 input legs and even though the majority of it will flow to ground through the input transistors, some of it still needs to flow out of the input pins in order to bias those transistors.

When you use the opamp in a circuit, you *must* provide a path for this *input bias current*.

In your circuit, all of the opamps inverting (-) inputs have a feedback resistor which does this job, and the first 3 have their non-inverting (+) inputs are either dc-coupled to each other or fed by a resistor voltage-divider.
But your 4th opamp is AC-coupled by C6 and has no DC path for the bias current being sourced by the non-inverting input.

The easiest way to fix this in your circuit would be to put a resistor in parallel with D1.
To calculate the value of this resistor ou need to take the value of the bias current and decide for yourself what the maximum permissible offset voltage you can tolerate at that point is. Ohm's law will then produce a value for you.
You'll also need to be aware that this will form a high-pass filter with C6.

Answer (score 2):

Take D1 off and try to create an ideal diode with the last of your op amp.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier
improved circuit of course !

I have tried to modify your schematics but I do not have circuit lab account.

Comment: You need a split supply for that right?

Comment: As is yes, as your own design !  It's just an inspiration. You can for example connect positive input to half value of Vbat.